# Scalamock: Unable to mock function with typed parameter and multiple implicit variables

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalatest, scalamock

This question is an extension of the solved issue mentioned at https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/79

I have the following trait to mock:

```
trait HttpClient{
   def deserialize[T](response: HttpResponse)
                    (implicit um: Unmarshaller[ResponseEntity, T],
                     executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[T]
}
```

I'm trying to mock the HttpClient as follows

```
val client = mock[HttpClient]

case class SomeTypeT(name:String, id:Int)
implicit val someTypeTFormat = jsonFormat2(SomeTypeT)   // to be able to marshal and unmarshal from JSON

(httpClient.deserialize[SomeTypeT](_: HttpResponse))
.expects(where {
  (response: HttpResponse) => {
    response.entity == ent
  }
})
.returns(Unmarshal(response.entity).to[SomeTypeT])
```

The problem occurs when I try to mock the deserialize function. As above, the `deserialize` method consists of a Typed Parameter `T` and a single parameter of type `HttpResponse`, and 2 more implicit parameters used while unmarshalling the response.

The question, therefore, is how to use ScalaMock to mock the `deserialize` function and specify multiple implicit parameters while mocking. This does not work

```
// Both UnMarshaller & ExecutionContext are available here as implicits
(httpClient.deserialize[SomeTypeT](_: HttpResponse)(_: Unmarshaller[ResponseEntity, SomeTypeT](_: ExecutionContext))
```

The problem is I cannot use `_` to specify both the implicit parameters. And I don't know how to achieve this. Please help how to mock the given function

I'm using the following libraries:

- scala version 2.11.8
- scalatest version 3.0.0
- scalamock version 3.5.0

While the second attempt does not even compile due to multiple `_` being used, the first one results in following exception:

```
org.scalamock.function.MockFunction3 cannot be cast to org.scalamock.function.MockFunction1
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.scalamock.function.MockFunction3 cannot be cast to org.scalamock.function.MockFunction1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer at GitHub that you linked, your code should be something like

```
(httpClient.deserialize[SomeTypeT](_: HttpResponse)(_:  Unmarshaller[ResponseEntity, SomeTypeT], _:ExecutionContext))
.expects(where {
  (response: HttpResponse, _:  Unmarshaller[ResponseEntity, SomeTypeT], _:ExecutionContext) => {
    response.entity == ent
  }
})
.returns(Unmarshal(response.entity).to[SomeTypeT])
```

I.e. you explicitly put placeholders for implicit parameters in the call as a second group of parameters and in the `where` as additional parameters after all non-implicit.

Comment: Thanks this works. I was missing adding the same implicit parameters in the where statement as you rightly pointed out.